# LINQ querying a many-to-many relationship

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities, many-to-many

I have an ASP.NET application that talks to an SQL database containing 4 tables:

- Cities
- States
- StatesCities (maps Cities<=>States)
- Customers (which stores the ID of the City they live in)

I need to get a count of how many customers live in a particular state. I can achieve this with the following SQL query:

```
select count(*) from Customers where CityID in 
(
    select sc.CityID from StatesCities sc, States s 
    where sc.StateID = s.StateID AND s.Name = 'Texas'
)
```

How can I express the equivalent of this query in LINQ, either using the EF or LINQ to SQL?

With the EF approach I've made it as far as:

`var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.States.Any(s => s.Name == "Texas"));`

but I'm not sure how to do the Customer/CityID match and count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@216 got me on the right track with the first suggestion, but because a City can exist in more than one State I needed to tweak the statement slightly:

```
int customersCount = db.Customers.Count(c => c.City.States.Any(s => s.Name == "Texas"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
int CustomersCount=db.Customers.Count(c=>c.City.State.Name=="Texas");
```

or

```
var cities = db.Cities.Where(c => c.States.Any(s => s.Name == "Texas"));
int customersCount=Customers.Count(d=>cities.Any(x=>d.CityID==x.CityID);
```